# How to load 2 level items to DataGridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, parent-child, inotifypropertychanged

I have bounded 2 levels of data to the MS DataGridView. The child table which is populated through Complex property is not visible. Is there any customization I have to do to enable nested table view in `DataGridView` Please refer to the attached sample.

Here is my DataSource class.

```
public class Level1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool a;
    bool dispatch, abandon;
    List<Level2> sample2data = new List<Level2>();

    // private Sample2 sampleval;
    public Level1(bool value, bool disp, bool aban, List<Level2> val)
    {
        a = value;
        dispatch = disp;
        abandon = aban;
        sample2data = val;

    }
    public bool Status
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; OnPropertyChanged("A"); }
    }

    public bool Dispatch
    {
        get { return dispatch; }
        set
        {
            dispatch = value;
            sample2data.ForEach(item => item.SampleA = false);
            OnPropertyChanged("Dispatch");
        }

    }
    public bool Abandon
    {
        get { return abandon; }
        set { abandon = value; sample2data.ForEach(item => item.SampleB = true); OnPropertyChanged("Abandon"); }
    }

    public List<Level2> Sample2
    {
        get { return sample2data; }
        set
        {
            sample2data = value; OnPropertyChanged("Sample2");
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class Level2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Level2()
    {

    }
    public bool _a, _b;
    public bool SampleA
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; OnPropertyChanged("SampleA"); }
    }
    public bool SampleB
    {
        get { return _b; }
        set { _b = value; OnPropertyChanged("SampleB"); }
    }
    public bool SampleC
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}


class Data
{
    public List<Level1> level1Data = new List<Level1>();
    public List<Level2> level2Data = new List<Level2>();
    public List<Level1> Level1Data
    {
        get { return level1Data; }
        set { level1Data = value; }
    }
    public List<Level2> Level2Data
    {
        get { return level2Data; }
        set { level2Data = value; }
    }
    public Data()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var newLevel2data = new Level2
            {
                SampleC = false
            };
            level2Data.Add(newLevel2data);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            level1Data.Add(new Level1(false, false, false, level2Data));
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the data source loading code for `DataGridView`.

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = new Data();
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
this.dataGridView1.DataMember = "Level1Data";
```

And also I have one more question, When working with the complex property data in `DataGridView`, I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the property changes to the bound datasource of the grid. Although child table is not visible, I have changed some property values of the child class properties, `PropertyChanged` event for the child class is always null, so Property changed is not notified. But for parent class, the property changed is always notified.

To resolve the `PropertyChanged` becomes null for Child Class, I have hooked the `PropertyChanged` event for child class data, while creating values for child table list. By this, the properties are notified properly.

Here my question is that, Is there any specific reason or necessity to hook the PropertyChanged event for child class? Because no hookup is done for parent level class properties. and how to show child table in `DataGridView` with my data source?

Please let me know the necessity of hooking the `PropertyChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms `DataGridView` doesn't support binding for nested objects. You'll have to extend the original control to support it, so I suggest you to take a look at the following article:

[DataGridView: How to bind nested objects](http://www.developer-corner.com/blog/2007/07/19/datagridview-how-to-bind-nested-objects/)

The source code for the article can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/jeden/DataGridViewSample).

If the above article doesn't work for you, just search for `Nested Windows Forms DataGridView`on your favorite search engine. There are lots of similar resources since the problem you have is very common.

**Edit:** I missed your question about the `PropertyChanged` event. You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in both classes for it to work properly.